# How to allow Label Font text colors in Delphi? ( Custom Styles issue )

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio, vcl-styles

I am trying to set Label font colors, like this:

[image: See Image]

- TLabel1.Font.Color := clGreen;
- TLabel2.Font.Color := clBlue;
- TLabel3.Font.Color := clRed;

But when I choose a Custom Style:

- Project -> Options -> Application -> Appearance -> Custom Styles
- Enable 'TableDark' and set it as the 'Default style':

[image: See Image]

And then run the program, this is what I get:

[image: See Image]

The Label font color goes back to white (this only happen if I use one of the Custom Styles), but I really need the custom Styles ON in my program, and I also want the font colors for the Labels to remain colored and not white.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Is this with VCL or FMX? If VCL, have you tried removing the `seFont` bit from the `TLabel.StyleElements` property? If FMX, have you tried using `TLabel.FontColor` instead of `TLabel.Font.Color`, or removing the `FontColor` bit from the `TLabel.StyledSettings` property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Vcl Styles determine the properties (like e.g. color) of a labels text. This can, however, be overruled by

- removing `seFont` from the labels `StyleElements`
- changing `Font` properties as needed

In code you can e.g. write

```
  Label4.StyleElements := Label4.StyleElements - [seFont];
  Label4.Font.Color := clRed;
```